# How to get rid of whitespace around image file?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, eps

I could not delete the extra white space around a `.eps` file in Ubuntu 12.04. I have done the same, using the command `fixbb <inputfile.eps> <outputfile.eps>` in earlier versions but in this version, whenever I try, I get the messeage `fixbb:command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do simple scripting for doing that

```
   ls | grep " " | while read -r file_name ; do mv -v "$file_name" `echo $file_name | tr -d ' '` ; done
```

before doing that you need to enter into that directory then execute the script.

you can also use alias here to call it with out using whole command everytime.

in the terminal do as ,

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and in that text file at the last place paste the above script as

```
alias fixb='ls | grep " " | while read -r file_name ; do mv -v "$file_name" `echo $file_name | tr -d ' '` ; done'
```

then save and close with CTRL+X & Y.

now in the terminal type as

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to reload the bashrc file. now you can simply remove all the spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did everything but when in the terminal i typed the command source ~/.bashrc the following message was displayed bash: alias:  | while read -r file_name ; do mv -v   ; done: not found

Comment: I think there has been some confusion here - the `fixbb` command referred to by the original poster is almost certainly a Ghostscript script to modify the bounding box around an image file - nothing to do with removing whitespace from file*names*. FYI an implementation of the `fixbb` script seems to be available from the gnuplot website http://www.gnuplot.info/scripts/ (although I can't be sure that is exactly the script you used before).